# Where clause on custom column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

```
select c.base_id,case when c.type is not null then c.type else g.type end as type, c.function_id
from cust c 
left join category cg on c.cat_id=cg.id
where c.type='privelleged'; --- where clause is not working as expected
```

What am I missing in the above query.The where clause is not working as expected.
I need to apply the where clause on the derived 'type' column. How do I acheive that in Oracle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Privileged" is a word in English.  "privelleged" is not.  Perhaps that has something to do with the issue.

Comment: `c.type` refers to the column `type` in table `cust`. If you want to reuse an expression then you will need an inline view or CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you just want `coalesce()` -- in both the `select` and `where`:

```
select c.base_id, coalesce(c.type, g.type) as type, c.function_id
from cust c left join
     category cg
     on c.cat_id = cg.id
where coalesce(c.type, g.type) = 'privileged';
```

Comment: This works like a charm..real short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that *derived* column the way you wanted - you need to use the same CASE in WHERE as well:

```
select c.base_id,
  case when c.type is not null then c.type 
       else g.type 
  end as type, 
  c.function_id
from cust c 
left join category cg on c.cat_id = cg.id
where case when c.type is not null then c.type     --> here
           else g.type 
      end = 'privelleged';
```

Alternatively, use current query as a CTE (or a subquery) and apply filter on it:

```
with temp as
  (select c.base_id,
          case when c.type is not null then c.type 
               else g.type 
          end as type, 
          c.function_id
   from cust c 
   left join category cg on c.cat_id = cg.id
  )
select *
from temp
where type = 'privelleged';
```